# Binding Master/Detail to Master/Detail?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding, master-detail

My question is how does one tie two master/detail sources together. I am working in C# winforms and using VS 2017. My situation is I have 4 tables (LETTINGS, LINK_CONTRACT_LETTING, CONTRACTS, DESES) from an Access Database, that I am bringing into a dataset, which has four tables and three table relationships. See Image. [Tables and Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWBw9.jpg)

The CONTRACTS and DESES tables are bound to the textboxes on the form and these textboxes change to the next or previous record properly. The binding source code for the CONTRACTS parent table is:

```
//Contracts Binding
bsContracts = new BindingSource();
bsContracts.DataSource = dsPlanning;                    //DataSet
bsContracts.DataMember = contracts.TableName;       //DataTable
```

The binding source code for the Deses child table is:

```
//Deses Binding
bsDeses = new BindingSource();              //Deses has a Details relationship to Contracts as in Master to Details. Therefore this binding is different.
bsDeses.DataSource = bsContracts;           //Master binding source bsContracts
bsDeses.DataMember = "ContToDes";       //"ContToDes" is the data relationship between the Contracts and Deses tables.
```

I also have done the same thing to the LETTINGS table and the LINK_CONTRACT_LETTING table master/detail like so:

```
//Lettings Binding
bsLettings = new BindingSource();
bsLettings.DataSource = dsPlanning;                     //DataSet
bsLettings.DataMember = lettings.TableName ;        //DataTable

//Links Binding
bsLinks = new BindingSource();
bsLinks.DataSource = bsLettings;        //Master binding source bsLettings
bsLinks.DataMember = "LetToLink";       //"ContToLink" is the data relationship between the Contracts and Link tables.
```

These additional 2 tables work together just like the first 2 tables.

I am not sure how to link the LINK_CONTRACT_LETTING to the CONTRACTS table so that when a letting is selected only the contracts and deses associated with that letting are shown? Is this possible or should I be doing something else? If I should be doing something else can you give me some direction?

I have tried changing the datasource and datamember for bsContracts and bsLinks, but so far nothing has worked. Can I have a master/detail tied into another master/detail?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: What are you binding this data to? You mentioned that the … _”tables are bound to the textboxes on the form “textboxes”…”_ … ? … So, you have a text box for each field in the table? I am just not picturing how you would do a master-detail with just text boxes. Typically, you would see a master-detail using two grids or more. Is there some reason you don’t use a grid(s)?

Comment: @JohnG I was asked to provide textboxes after I had shown the user grids. Yes I do have textboxes for each field. I also have two binding navigators for the contracts and deses tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Automatic filtering through binding only works from master to detail over a one-to-many relationship. When you have a third table linking two others in a many-to-many relationship, you have two masters and one detail. You cannot select a master record at one end and have that automatically filter the master records at the other end. You can automatically filter as far as the link table, but then you need to manually filter the other master. For instance, you can select a Letting record and have the `BindingSource` for the link table filter automatically. You then need to gather the IDs from that `BindingSource` and use them to filter the `BindingSource` for the Contract table, e.g.

```vb
var contIds = bsLinks.Cast<DataRowView>().Select(drv => drv.Row.Field<int>("ContId"));

bsContracts.Filter = $"ContId IN ({string.Join(", ", contIds)})";
```

Comment: Thank you! I very much appreciate it. I am just learning C# and I have been trying to figure this problem out for several days. Your response was well written, makes very good sense and is to the point. 
I would appreciate it if you would help me out with your first line of code. I am getting a red line under the word “.Select”.
“BindingSource does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no accessible extension method 'select' accepting a first arugument of type 'BindingSource' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)”

Comment: I must have left off the user name for the Thank you! comment above.

Comment: @SerialCoder, I have updated my code to address that issue.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. The updated code works perfectly. This is the first question that I have asked on this forum so if I do not do something correctly, please let me know and I will fix it. I will mark the question accepted and I sincerely appreciate it.